# Is there a difference in meaning of the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions

With an uncharacteristic dispatch, bureaucrats rendered a judgement **of** history in six weeks.

With an uncharacteristic dispatch, bureaucrats rendered a judgement **on** history in six weeks.

Comment: Either preposition is OK, but the idiom is anarthrous; should be _with uncharacteristic dispatch_, no article.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, John. Is there any nuance to "judgment of history"? Does it indicate a superficial judgment as opposed to in-depth judgment conveyed by "judgment on history"?

Comment: There's a fusty old idiom, "the judgement of history" which means what things look like a century or two later.